# how to read a single firebase database value at a specific time

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to read a value in a firebase database at a certain time. Additionally i'd prefer to NOT have the read value updated even if the dataBases voteValue changes at some time later. Though if its easier i guess i'd go with it.

I have a number of time slots in my firebase database - they happen to be time in seconds. I have called these timeSlots and I have a vote value at each of these timeSlots.

so in the example below, say the time is @ 11seconds. i want to read that the vote for that timeSlot has a value of 8

[image]

Currently i have:

```
var ref = new Firebase ('https://aB8ppi-f0h02.firebaseio.com/web/data');
function myFunction (x) {
  ct = player.getCurrentTime()
  timeSlot = Math.round(ct)    
  var voteData = ref.child("vid1");
  voteData.orderByValue().equalTo(timeSlot).on("value", function(dataSnapshot) {
    var Yval =  dataSnapshot.vote + x;
  };
```

//then update the dBase to the new value

```
voteData.child("slot" + timeSlot).set({
    slot: timeSlot,
    vote: Yval
});
```

};

Firebase seems well setup for onChange events etc, but i don't need that here.  Note: i do NOT want the client to have to login / auth.

Can you suggest how i can retrieve, change and set a new value to a firebase database? Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

Alright worked it out. What i found was that i needed to clean up BOTH the writing to the dBase and the reading from it too. I hope this helps someone else one day :)

The writing function is now

```
ref.child("vid1/slot"+timeSlot+"/vote").on("value",function(snapshot){
    slotVal = (snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("the read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
ref.child("vid1/slot"+timeSlot).set({
    vote: slotVal + x
});
```

and the reading function:

```
ref.child("vid1/slot"+timeSlot+"/vote").on("value",function(snapshot){
    //console.log(snapshot.val());
    slotVal = (snapshot.val());
}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("the read failed: " + errorObject.code); 
    slotVal = 0; // better than returning null, eh?
});
return (slotVal);
```